# Is there anything like SHA1CryptoServiceProvider (Which is C#) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, sha1

I am trying to create a serial number checker in an app that I am writing, and it uses cryptography to encode the name and entered number  against what it actually should be.  I am familiar with the SHA1CryptoServiceProvider used in C#, but is there anything like this in Objective-C?

Here is sample code from C# that I want to convert to **Objective-C**:

```
string license = txtnLicense.Text;
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider provider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        string finalLicense = BitConverter.ToString(provider.ComputeHash(bytes));
        bool isGood = (BitConverter.ToString(provider.ComputeHash(bytes)).Replace("-", "") == license.Replace("-", ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS X comes with an easy-to-use encryption and hashing library built-in called CommonCrypto. You don't have to link against anything special to use it. See the headers in /usr/include/CommonCrypto for its interface and [CC_SHA1(3cc)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CC_SHA1.3cc.html) for docs.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that either, I will look at that as well!

Answer (score 2):

[using openssl for license keys](http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2004/09/05/using-openssl-for-license-keys/) shows how to use SHA1. It may be a good start.

Comment: Thank you! 
I will definitely have a go at it.